# How to intepret Keras Dense layer with rank of 3

Tags: keras, layer, softmax

I am using Keras and Tensorflow. I understand that Dense lyer with softmax activation will output a set of probablities. Suddenly, I notice that other people use Dense layer with softmax activation which its ouput is a tensor with rank of 3.

[image: model plotting]

My question is how to interpret this output with rank of 3 if it is a classification problem?

The code to produce the output of Dense layer with rank of 3:

    `model.add(Conv3D(32, (1,2,2), padding="same", input_shape=(32, 224, 224, 3)))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D((2,2,2)))
    model.add(Conv3D(64, (1,2,2), padding="same"))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D((2,2,2)))
    model.add(Conv3D(128, (1,2,2), padding="same"))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D((4,4,4)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='softmax'))
    model.add(Reshape((32, 32)))
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Dense(11, activation="softmax", name="fc"))`

Comment: There is no way to interpret this without more context, where are these figures coming from?

Comment: I dont remember where this architecture comes from. But, for picture in the right, I remember that they employ 32 frames from a video. So, can I interpret like this: "the authors try to classify a frame one by one into predefined class". Am I correct?

Comment: Can you please share the code of your model?

Comment: The output shape seems to be of (32, 11 ). Maybe the whole clip consisting of 32 frames was an input for CNN. The output was the class probabilities for 11 classes of 32 frames. Each of the 32 frames corresponds to one of the 11 labels.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal, I also thought so. But I confused if "32" still considered as "frame" because `Flatten()` layer is introduced in the network. I know that `Flatten()` layer will make the input squeezed.

Comment: in the rank 3 example you have a softmax over a vocal of 11 on a sequence of 32 items.